# Show AJAX div when image hovered and follow the mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I need help. I'm working on a website that's give user a download link to movies.

But I can't get the **preview_block div(id) showed up when the mouse is hovered** on the **movie_block div(id)** element. I can't even make the div(preview_block) **follow my mouse when I hovered** it.

Also, I'm planning to make an **AJAX request** on the **preview_block div(id)** to get information about the movie hovered.

Here's my code.

A simpler fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/o4xcb9m0/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="includes/styles.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="">
            <div id="preview_block" style="display:none"><p>test</p></div>
            <table>
                <!-- -->
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="download-link"><span id="movie_block"><img src="image-link" alt="<?php echo $movieNameList->data->movies[0]->title; ?>" /></span></a>
                        <br>
                        <a href="download-link">Movie Name</a>
                        <br>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="download-link"><span id="movie_block"><img src="image-link" alt="<?php echo $movieNameList->data->movies[0]->title; ?>" /></span></a>
                        <br>
                        <a href="download-link">Movie Name</a>
                        <br>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- -->
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="download-link"><span id="movie_block"><img src="image-link" alt="<?php echo $movieNameList->data->movies[0]->title; ?>" /></span></a>
                        <br>
                        <a href="download-link">Movie Name</a>
                        <br>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="download-link"><span id="movie_block"><img src="image-link" alt="<?php echo $movieNameList->data->movies[0]->title; ?>" /></span></a>
                        <br>
                        <a href="download-link">Movie Name</a>
                        <br>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <script src="includes/scripts.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to have duplicate id tags

Comment: which one? the movie_block one? nah I only planned to make this id tag have only one function, which is the one I'm referring to this problem.

Comment: It's still a bad idea. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really  If you want a good answer, you should simplify your code as much as possible. Show me the minimum example that is not working.

Comment: on the 21 line of the code

Comment: sorry for the long and complicated code.

Comment: Usually, questions don't get a good answer when you say things like: "I need this. And also this, and this." Try to be specific and help us to answer a part of what you are trying to solve. It may point you in the correct direction faster. :)

Comment: Issue is that you `n` number of `id="movie_block"`, where `id` should be unique. Since javascript/jQuery knows that there should be only 1 `id="movie_block"` in your document your `$("#movie_block").hover(function(event)` will find the first one and bind to that, and never bind to the others. Try changing to `class="movie_block"` and `$(".movie_block").hover(function(event)`.

Comment: @Sean it's still doesn't work. although, there's a different between movie_block and preview_block. don't forget to notice it :)

Comment: Pls do not post server side code for questions related to jQuery/JS. Post the generated source.

Comment: @JonathanO first, sorry for not being specific on this matter. second, could you explain me which id tags that I'm duplicating?

Comment: @lshettyl sorry, although the php source are pretty useless in this situation. i'll remove them now so maybe you could help me

Comment: If this is your actual code, where do you load your jQuery library? ie. `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @Sean I've triend a simple code without jquery just like this: https://jsfiddle.net/o4xcb9m0/1/

Comment: Actually that jsfiddle code example uses jquery. @JonathanO uses `jQuery 2.1.3` and `$(selector).hover(function(event){ });` is a jquery method. So I still don't see how you can have `$(".movie_block").hover(function(event)` in your code, and not include the jQuery library.

Comment: oh sorry. after I implemented the jQuery library, the preview_block div just appeared at the above of the page when I hovered to it.

Comment: now my problems are gone. I have find out why my problem occurs. it is because I accidently missed out     rel="stylesheet"    on my html external style. sorry and thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you'd be better off using mouse(enter/leave) events as the hover event bubbles up from within the inner most child (`img` in your case) to the element (`span` in your case) the event is registered to. Mouse(enter/leave) events are almost the same as `hover` except that they don’t react to event bubbling. Therefore they see the entire HTML element they’re registered to as one solid block and don’t react to mouseovers and –outs taking place inside the block.

There is a good interactive demo on the [jQuery mouseover docs](https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) at the bottom of the page that explains this.

Make sure you change all occurrences of `id="movie_block"` to `class="movie_block"` as `ID`s are **supposed to be unique** in any given HTML document. They'd make your HTML invalid otherwise.

```
$(".movie_block").on({
    mouseenter: function(event) {
        $("#preview_block").css({top: event.clientY, left: event.clientX}).show();
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $("#preview_block").hide();
    }
});
```

Here is [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sgxnx35u/) that has the working code.

And if you wanted the preview block to follow the mouse pointer, then you may use the following.

```
$(".movie_block").on({
    mousemove: function(event) {
        $("#preview_block").css({top: event.clientY, left: event.clientX}).show();
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $("#preview_block").hide();
    }
});
```

[A demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sgxnx35u/1/) for the above.

Comment: your code is actually working but it seems like I can't find the difference on my code with yours. could you explain what code have you changed?

Answer (score 0):

So Id's aside here, It seems to me that you are using the hover event when you should be using the mousemove event http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/

Here is a link [How to get the coordinates in html using .hover event in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986312/how-to-get-the-coordinates-in-html-using-hover-event-in-jquery)

Hover does not fire continuously. So it won't move with the mouse. [How to get the coordinates in html using .hover event in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986312/how-to-get-the-coordinates-in-html-using-hover-event-in-jquery)

In reference to keeping your code clean and easy to get answered, try posting it on jsFiddle like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/o4xcb9m0/1/

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="">

            <a href="foo.com" >Foo
                <span class="movie_block">
                    Bar
                    <img src="foo" />
                </span>
            </a>      
            <div class="preview_block" style="display:none"><p>test</p></div>
        </div>

        <script>
            $(".movie_block").hover(function(event) {
                $(".preview_block").css({color: 'red', top: event.clientY + 'px', left: event.clientX + 'px'}).show();
            }, function() {
                $(".preview_block").hide();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```